# Keras model with layout error:The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a model with Keras and I get the following warning from TensorFlow:

```
2020-04-30 13:23:22.127144: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] layout failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.132082: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] remapper failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/activation_1_loss/categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/activation_1_loss/categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.151325: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.161224: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.235462: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] arithmetic_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.240014: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] remapper failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/activation_1_loss/categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/activation_1_loss/categorical_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.246225: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.252494: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-04-30 13:23:22.271708: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_function_library_runtime.cc:697] Ignoring multi-device function optimization failure: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
```

My model definition is as follows:

```
bi_gram_input = Input(shape=(100, 26))
bi_gram_embedding = Embedding(4289, 20, input_shape=(100, 26))(bi_gram_input)

tri_gram_input = Input(shape=(100, 25))
tri_gram_embedding = Embedding(32828, 20, input_shape=(100, 25))(tri_gram_input)

qua_gram_input = Input(shape=(100, 24))
qua_gram_embedding = Embedding(123773, 20, input_shape=(100, 24))(qua_gram_input)

final_added = Concatenate(axis=-2)([bi_gram_embedding, tri_gram_embedding, qua_gram_embedding])
flattened = TimeDistributed(Flatten(input_shape=(75, 20)))(final_added)
lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))(flattened)
dropout1 = Dropout(0.3)(lstm1)
dense1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(56))(dropout1)
dropout2 = Dropout(0.2)(dense1)
dense2 = TimeDistributed(Dense(4))(dropout2)
output = Activation('softmax')(dense2)
```

what might be the problem and how could I fix it?

Comment: Can you please share the complete code or reproducible code for the error? I built a model using the data provided by you and it compiled fine.

Comment: Also what is the version of tensorflow you are using?